# If not disabled, then disable it and again enable with selection

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script which run my model after modifying another file. e.g.,

```
$cat myscript.sh
 cp myfile DELHI
 ./mymodel.exe (This will execute with DELHI information)
$cat DELHI
 ! If you enable an input below, then the information 
 ! of the corresponding city will be passed to the model
   x = 150
   y = 150
 ! input = 'KOLKATA'
 ! input = 'MUMBAI'
  input = 'DELHI'
 ! input = 'CHENNAI'
 ......
 ......
 so on to 100 Cities
```

All the inputs (KOLKATA, MUMBAI, ... ) are actually different files that contains many other information

So I need to enable few cities upon my interest one by one and execute the model. Manually it takes a lot time. So if can put it into a script, then it would save many times.

My script/algorithm is

```
  for city in KOLKATA MUMBAI DELHI CHENNAI;do
     cp myfile $city
     check all cities in '$city file' are disabled except one (that is to be executed)
     ./mymodel.exe
  done
```

I am helpless how to give the check command.

Comment: Why do you need to keep all cities in the file, with most of them commented out?  Why not prepare the city file in such a way that it has just one line for the needed city, without having to comment anything?

Comment: Or pass the city directly to `./mymodel.exe` as the first argument, e.g. `./mymodel.exe city_name`.

Comment: I understand your points, but I need in this way. because there are many more information to provide in the same manner.... I had asked here just for an example....   @codeforester.. The cities are not commented. They are disabled only. I need to execute one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You an use `sed`:

- For all lines start with some space and then "input", insert a `!`
- For all lines start with `! input = 'YOURCITY'`, remove the `!`

Like this:

```
sed -i -e 's/^ *input/ ! input/' -e '/^ ! input = '"'$city'"'/s/ !/ /' "$city"
```

You can call this in a loop for each `city`.